# How can I make network signal map?

Tags: qgis

Currently, I am planning a research on the relation between mobile signal and poverty.

I found that telecommunications companies provide maps of their signal coverage like the links. http://www.sensorly.com/map/2G-3G/ID/Indonesia/Telkomsel/gsm_51010#|coverage

[image]
Is there any way that I can import the points in the map into qgis as vector or raster?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

(Note: Sensorly is not a telecommunications company. Sensorly is a private company not associated with any telco (as far as i can see) that creates its own coverage data)

You can (legally) get them into QGIS if the data provider (sensorly) provides the raw data. It does not seem to be the case.

You could write to them and ask, stating that you are doing research and your use of the data will be strictly noncommercial.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is meant for a small area, you can go for crowd sourced measurement apps which is available for free. Measurements of large area require another approach.